# Stop VMware Fusion from NAT'ing my VMs using my internal Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have two VMs that are NAT'd using the thunderbolt adapter connected to my Mac. However, when I connect to Wi-Fi on my Mac, my VMs' network settings reset to NAT using my Wi-Fi connection.

How can I leave my Wi-Fi connection on my Mac completely separate from VMware Fusion?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to write “bridged to the Thunderbolt [network] adapter”? Because NAT behaves just like a regular program would. If WiFi is the best (or even only!) route, it goes through there.

Comment: I don't want to bridge. I want my VMs to use NAT settings from my thunderbolt adapter and not my Wi-Fi adapter. Is there not a way to force VMware fusion to only use certain adapters?

Comment: I didn’t say you should bridge. I asked for a clarification. It seems you have a misunderstanding of how NAT with VMware works. It just looks at your routing table and takes the best route. Just like your browser does when connecting to a website.

Comment: Gotcha, well I didn't mean to write bridged because that's not what I wanted to do. :) However, with your additional clarification regarding "it just goes off the host OS's routes", I think I've determined where to go from here. :) Thanks